# Can't sculpt a specific area of a model

Tags: sculpting

I'm just learning Blender, and making a little head for practice. I want to make the temples a bit more set in, but for some reason none of the sculpt tools can affect that area of the head. The face is still sculptable, but even at full strength the upper sides of the head, back of the head, and neck are unaffected by any sculpting tools. What might cause this? There are plenty of polygons.

Comment: Make sure you didn't somehow mask them.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was the issue.